# Reading custom machine.config elements using XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument, machine.config

In machine.config file there are elements written there by 3rd party software so it looks like this:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    ...
    </configSections>

    ...

    <Custom>
        <Level1> ... 
        </Level1>

        <Level2> ... 
        </Level2>

        <Level3>
            <add key="key_text1" value="s1" />
            <add key="key_text2" value="s2" />
            <add key="key_text3" value="s3" />
        </Level3>
    </Custom>
</configuration>
```

I want to get e.g. a value ("s2") of "value" attribute where key="key_text2" from configuration/Custom/Level3 node. So far, I tried to open machine.config as an XML and work from there:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMachineConfiguration();
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(config.FilePath);
```

however, I get XmlException "Data at the root level is invalid.". I also don't know how to use Configuration class methods directly to get this done. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [RuntimeEnvironment.SystemConfigurationFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeenvironment.systemconfigurationfile.aspx) to get *machine.config* location:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(RuntimeEnvironment.SystemConfigurationFile);
```

Also why not to use Linq to Xml?

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(RuntimeEnvironment.SystemConfigurationFile);
var element = xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//Custom/Level3/add[@value='s2']");
if (element != null)
    key = (string)element.Attribute("key");
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful. Both answers (Animal's and yours) actually worked. However, instead of the above, I had to use  the following code to get it to work:


`var query = "/configuration/Custom/Level3/add[@value='s2']";
            
var dbElement1 = xdoc.XPathSelectElement(query);

string key = dbElement1.Attribute("value").Value;`

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `Load()` method instead of `LoadXml()`

```
doc.Load(config.FilePath);
```

I also sould suggest you have a look at XDocument instead of XmlDocument. **LINQ** will really be of use when getting that value from the config file.