# Accessing Customer Configuration Settings Child Nodes from Machine.Config in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to read Custom Configuration Settings defined in Machine.Config. Also I need to access some of the child nodes inside that.

Below is the configuration setttings in machine.config.... I need to access "connectionstring" value....

```
    <configuration>
    <commonsettings>
      <setting environment="dev">
       <common>
        <connectionstring>value</connectionstring>
       <common>
      </setting>
     </commonsettings>
    </configuration>
```

Can anybody please help me writing the code for that ?

Comment: What have tried? Do you have any existing code? Writing a config section is quite straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways the machine configuration can be read.

1. Using the .net provided [OpenMachineConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openmachineconfiguration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method
     The issues with this is all the sections have to have a readable/deserializable objects
2. The other method is to read the machine configuration just as any other xml. For this .net gives the machineconfig.xml path using the property  [RuntimeEnvironment.SystemConfigurationFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeenvironment.systemconfigurationfile.aspx)

   Once the machine config path is known, the following code snippet can help load the file

   ```
   XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(RuntimeEnvironment.SystemConfigurationFile);
   ```

   Using the xdoc.XPathSelectElement method the respective values from the xml can be read as detailed in this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498130/reading-custom-machine-config-elements-using-xmldocument)

   ```
    string connectionString = string.Empty;
    var element = xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//commonsettings/common/connectionstring");
    if (element != null)
        connectionString = (string)element.Value;
   ```

Comment: I have to use framework 2.0 so cant use LINQ, but i tried with xmldocument and it works. Now the issue is I cant read the same keys when that section is encrypted, as we need to encrypt that section and then read it...After encryption that block looks like <commonsettings     configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
  <EncryptedData> encrypted value </EncryptedData>
 </commonsettings>